# Comparative Boxplot

Tags: r, data-visualization

[image: Crashdata]

I am attempting to make two comparative boxplots in R Studio. One between the ageYrs variable and the Other Crash level of the A_DIST variable and the other between ageYrs and the Involving a Distracted Driver level of A_DIST. How do I do this? the type.crash variable is also essentially the same thing as the A_DIST variable with "2" meaning Other Crash and "1" meaning Involving a Distracted Driver so am I supposed to use that instead? Thanks for any help.

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you're asking here - if you are asking how to code this in R, then that would be off-topic here.

Comment: Where do I ask it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: If you're just interested in the code then Stack Overflow is a more relevant place to ask, but you'd need to add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
for people to work with and it would almost certainly be closed as a duplicate. Have a look at the comparative box plot questions there already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do `boxplot(ageYrs ~ A_DIST, data = dat)` where `dat` is the name of the data frame.

It will create box plots of `ageYrs` for each level of the `A_DIST` variable.